# Deleting properties from nested objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Having an object like this one:

```json
{
    "status": "OK",
    "initialState": {
        "id": "dc3c89d27fd2aae78287c53f952c3b6a",
        "product": {
            "productName": "Cars",
            "description": null
        },
        "models": {
            "Toyota Avensis": {
                "id": "Toyota Avensis",
                "parent": "sedan",
                "required": false,
                "disabled": true,
                "visibility": true,
                "error": false
            },
            "Toyota Corolla": {
                "id": "Toyota Corolla",
                "parent": "sedan",
                "required": true,
                "disabled": false,
                "visibility": true,
                "error": false
            },
            "Ford Focus": {
                "id": "Ford Focus",
                "parent": "sedan",
                "required": false,
                "disabled": true,
                "visibility": true,
                "error": false
            },
            "Ford Mondeo": {
                "id": "Ford Mondeo",
                "parent": "sedan",
                "required": false,
                "disabled": true,
                "visibility": true,
                "error": false
            }
        },
        "userId": "user1",
        "status": 1
    }
}
```

I was trying to delete properties like `disabled` and `error` from the `initialState.models` objects.

My last attempt was unsuccessful though. What I tried was something like (assuming that the object above is stored as `const myObject`):

```js
Object.entries(myObject.initialState.models).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    Object.entries(value).forEach(([subKey, subValue]) => {
        if (subKey === 'disabled') {
            delete myObject.initialState.models[value.disabled];
        }
    });
});
```

But that way, nothing was deleted. What should be done to remove properties like `disabled` and `error` uncoditionally?

Comment: `value.disabled` is either `true` or `false`. Neither of these is a key in `myObject.initialState.models`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of iterating through the keys and values of each model, you can directly delete the `disabled` and `error` keys from each model:

```
Object.entries(myObject.initialState.models).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    delete value.disabled;
    delete value.error;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is the best way to handle this. What mistake you did is following

```
Object.entries(obj.initialState.models).forEach(([key, value]) => {
Object.entries(value).forEach(([subKey, subValue]) => {
    if (subKey === 'disabled') {
        delete obj.initialState.models[key].disabled; // Here you did mistake
        delete obj.initialState.models[key].error;
    }
});});
```